# Django URL in template NoReverseMatch

Tags: django, url, namespaces

I keep getting a `NoReverseMatch` in my base template, though I've specified a namespace and have put the proper name.

Error:

> Reverse for `'home'` with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: `['forum/|^forums/$']`

Main `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from forum.views import main_home

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', main_home, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/|^account/', include('accounts.urls', 
    namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^forum/|^forums/', include('forum.urls', namespace='forum')),
]
```

Forum urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from forum import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

From my template:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'forum:home' %}">Forum</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for [`reverse()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) say You cannot reverse url patterns that contain alternative choices using `|`.

In this case, you could change the URL to:

```
url(r'^forums?/', include('forum.urls', namespace='forum')),
```

However, it might be better to choice a single URL `/forums/` or `/forum/`. Having a single URL can be better for SEO.